# Add name for pasted cell

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably the simplest request anyone has every seen, but please humor me as I'm still a beginner. Essentially I'm cutting and pasting data from multiple worksheets into one. I'm trying to put text into column B that would specify what was pasted. Here is what I have so far, as well as where I'm trying to go with it (see notes):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DoStuff()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim summary As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab_Upload")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)) = "_" Then
        ws.Range("A23").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" & summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        ws.Range("H13:S13").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" & summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Offset(-1, 7)
'Place a line here that would say, "Funded Fixed Price Sub" in column B
        ws.Range("A23").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" & summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        ws.Range("H14:S14").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" & summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Offset(-1, 7)
'Place a line here that would say, "Unfunded Fixed Price Sub" in column B

    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Was @TonyDallimore answer satisfying? If not I can try to give it a go. If it was, please mark it so :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not a full answer because it is nearly midnight here and I am going to bed.

Your code is so difficult to understand because of the way you determine the destination row for each copy.  Where did you get that technique?

I determine the next free row at the beginning of the routine and then step the row number when appropriate.  No negative row offset so I always know where I am.

I think this code does what you seek.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub DoStuff()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim summary As Worksheet
  Dim RowTabCrnt As Long

  Set summary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab_Upload")

  ' Determine next free row in worksheet Tab_UpLoad
  ' Note if worksheet is empty, RowTabCrnt will be set to 2.
  With Worksheets("Tab_Upload")
    RowTabCrnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End With

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' LCase removed because underscore is not affected by LCase
    If Left(ws.Name, 1) = "_" Then

      ws.Range("A23").Copy Destination:=summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "A")
      ws.Range("H13:S13").Copy Destination:=summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "H")
      summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "B").Value = "Funded Fixed Price Sub"

      RowTabCrnt = RowTabCrnt + 1     ' Advance to next row

      ws.Range("A23").Copy Destination:=summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "A")
      ws.Range("H14:S14").Copy Destination:=summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "H")
      summary.Cells(RowTabCrnt, "B").Value = "Unfunded Fixed Price Sub"

      RowTabCrnt = RowTabCrnt + 1     ' Advance to next row

    End If

  Next ws

End Sub
```